# Gecode, error while compiling program with gecode.int.hh

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, gecode

I installed Gecode 6.0 for VS 2017. Added directories to /lib and /include. Then included gecode/int.hh to the Hello World program. During compilation got 3 strange errors:

Error   C2084   function "void Gecode::cmb_hash(size_t &,::size_t)" already has a body  ConsoleApplication3 c:\program files\gecode\include\gecode\support\hash.hpp 61

Error C2264 "Gecode::cmb_hash": error in fuction definition or declaration; function not called ConsoleApplication3 c:\program files\gecode\include\gecode\support\hash.hpp 62

Error C2264 "Gecode::cmb_hash": error in fuction definition or declaration; function not called ConsoleApplication3 c:\program files\gecode\include\gecode\int\extensional\dfa.hpp  100

Does anybody know how to get rid of these errors?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it. I have got x64 Gecode version installed but compiled my program for x86. Switched to x64 in VS2017 and everything is now working.